# Mathematica parametric equations and list plot

Tags: list, plot, wolfram-mathematica, equation

x = e^1/2*Cos((pi/4)t) + Cos(2Pi*t)
y = e^1/3*1/2Sin(pi*t) + sin(2pi * t)

t E [a,b] where 'a' and 'b' are inputted via input. How can I draw where 't' is in the moments t = a, a+1, a+2, ..., b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you mean by `How can I draw where t is'. But if you want to draw`ParametricPlot`in`t` the command is

```
x = Exp[1/2]*Cos[(Pi/4) t] + Cos[2 Pi*t] ;
y = Exp[1/3]*1/2 Sin[Pi*t] + Sin[2 Pi*t];
a = -1; b = 1;
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {t, a, b}]
```

[image]